# How to loop over a List while its contents contain a subvalue?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse out this single method which has over 8,000 lines of hardcoded data validation. Most of which is identical, duplicated logic for different fields in the data source.

A lot of it looks something like this (C++):

```
temp_str = _enrollment->Fields->FieldByName("ID")->AsString.SubString(1,2);
if (temp_str.IsEmpty())
    { /* do stuff */ }
else
{
  if (!IsDigitsOnly(temp_str))
      { /* do different stuff */ }
  else
      { /* do other stuff */ }
}

temp_str = _enrollment->Fields->FieldByName("OtherField");
if (temp_str.IsEmpty())
    /* do more stuff */
```

So basically, I just need to parse out values between each pair of `temp_str = ...` and then get each unique validation "chunk".

The problem I'm having currently is identifying where each "chunk" begins and ends.

This is the code I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = @"C:\somePathToFile.h";
    string validationHeader = "temp_str = _enrollment->Fields->FieldByName(";
    string outputHeader = "=====================================================";
    int startOfNextValidation;

    List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList<string>();
    List<string> validations = new List<string>();

    while (lines.Contains(validationHeader))
    {

        //lines[0] should be the "beginning" temp_str assignment of the validation
        //lines[startOfNextValidation] should be the next temp_str assignment
        startOfNextValidation = lines.IndexOf(validationHeader, lines.IndexOf(validationHeader) + 1);

        //add the lines within that range to another collection
        //  to be iterated over and written to a textfile later
        validations.Add((lines[0] + lines[startOfNextValidation]).ToString());

        //remove everything up to startOfNextValidation so we can eventually exit
        lines.RemoveRange(0, startOfNextValidation);
    }

    StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"C:\someOtherPathToFile.txt");

    foreach (var v in validations.Distinct())
    {
        sw.WriteLine(v);
        sw.WriteLine(outputHeader);
    }

    sw.Close();
}
```

My `while` statement is never hit and it just immediately jumps to the `StreamWriter` creation, which creates an empty text file since `validations` is empty.

So I guess my first question is, how do you loop over a `List` while checking to make sure there are still items containing a particular "subvalue" within those items?

Edit:

I tried this as well;

```
while (lines.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(validationHeader)))
```

Per this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/18767402/1189566

But it says it can't convert from a `string` to a `bool`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
while (lines.Any(x => x.Contains(validationHeader)))
```

This checks whether the `validationHeader` is  a part of any string in the list.

> I tried this as well;
>
> ```
> while (lines.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(validationHeader)))
> ```

This won't work, because LINQ's `Where` method will return an `IEnumerable<string>` in your case. And the `while` loop needs a boolean predicate. An `IEnumerable` cannot be `true` or `false`, thus the compiler is complaining.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue, now to figure out the rest of my logic problems

Answer (score 0):

simple one to check if it has the needed value or not

```
foreach (var setting in FullList)
{
    if(cleanList.Exists(x => x.ProcedureName == setting.ProcedureName)) 
       setting.IsActive = true; // do you business logic here 
    else
       setting.IsActive = false;
    updateList.Add(setting);
}
```