# check whether a string exists in list using for loop in c#

Tags: c#

I have a list `arrString` that contains string values. I need to check a string `lookupvalue.Longname` whether it exists in the list using for loop in C#.

```
 for(int i = 0 ;i < ResoCustomFields.LongnameNotToBeTaken.Count ;i++)
 {
    string myStringList = ResoCustomFields.LongnameNotToBeTaken[i].ToString();
    var arrString = myStringList.Trim('(',')').Split(',').ToList();
    if(arrString.Contains(resoField))
    {
    // if(!arrString[i].Any(str=>str.ToString().Contains(lookupValue.LongName)))
    // if(lookupValue.LongName.Contains(arrString.ToString()))
    //(!arrString.Any(str => str.Equals(lookupValue.LongName)))
    // if(!arrString.Equals(lookupValue.LongName))                                                      
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if list contains element that contains a string and get that element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767302/check-if-list-contains-element-that-contains-a-string-and-get-that-element)

Comment: `if (ResoCustomFields.LongnameNotToBeTaken.Any(line => line.Trim('(',')').Split(',').Any(item => item == resoField))) {...}`

Comment: i tried arrString[i].Contains(lookupValue.LongName)..still its not working

Comment: i have already done trim and split..

Comment: Can you give a small example of arrString and resoField?

Comment: Why do you need to check the string after split? Before split only you can see if string contains the other string.

Comment: You could convert the list to an array and use `if(Array.IndexOf(myArray, myString) != -1) // if true, then array contains string`.

Comment: _"using for loop"_ -- is that really an implementation requirement? Or did you write that only because you can conceive of no other approach than to use a `for` loop? It matters greatly, because it determines what would or would not be an acceptable answer here. Note also that, without a good [mcve] illustrating your question and a precise problem statement, it's impossible to know exactly what you're asking.

Comment: split was used as the list contained opening and closing braces when converted string to list

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code :

```
int pos = Array.IndexOf(arrString, lookupValue.LongName);
if (pos > -1)
{
//// DO YOUR STUF
}
```

Following is the reference:

[Checking if a string array contains a value, and if so, getting its position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867377/checking-if-a-string-array-contains-a-value-and-if-so-getting-its-position)

Comment: i tried ,but the index is always -1 even if the string values contain in list.